# C# MVC publish to laptop

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-hosting

I'm kinda new to C# MVC publishing and want to know, can I use an old laptop as my server to host my site?
If so how can I do it?
If not is there a free host server? I've used my Azure trial..

Comment: If your IP is static or you buy DNS service, then yes you can.

Comment: @KarolisKajėnas My goal is to do it completely free since im planning to write lots of sites for practice. So if my IP is static how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

you can publish your C# app on a iis server on any PC (with system requirement on Microsoft website) and by a static ip you can access from out of home (for ex).
amazon hosting is low cast (is about free!)

Answer (score 0):

I use this site for get free host for asp.net but it's limited on Monthly transfer and Storage capacity.

[Free Asp.net Host](https://somee.com/FreeAspNetHosting.aspx)

Comment: ok i'll give it a try, thanks